# How to make a global navigation bar (one file on all pages)?

Tags: html, css

I looked around and couldn't find anything that solved my problem, though there were similar examples, I couldn't figure it out. I want to make my navbar (vertical).

I've attempted a solution with Javascript and PHP, neither of which I could get to work. I only know HTML and CSS, but am not opposed to learning other languages if they are useful with this sort of thing.

Here is my code, I'd like the navbar to be on every page, and have an editable "master file" instead of changing the content of the navbar manually every time it needs to be changed.

Additionally, if possible, I'd like to know how to make the current page "#active" if the navbar is loaded globally. Thanks in advance!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mainbg {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: calc (100vw - 17px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(https://i.imgur.com/NJqUx5y.png);
  background-attachment: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#active {
  border-left: 5px solid #feda6a;
}

#navlab {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.navbar {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(57, 63, 77, 0.8);
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 10%;
}

.navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #feda6a 50%, rgba(57, 63, 77, 0.0) 50%);
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-position: -100%, 0%;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mainbg">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <p id="navlab">CPPortfolio</p>
      <ul>
        <li><a id="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="hardware.html">Hardware</a></li>
        <li><a href="journal.html">Journal</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @MatejJ Not really sure what's wrong with my question, but I'd be glad to edit it if you could inform me. I read through the link but didn't see anything really wrong, unless I'm just dumb...

Comment: Check this out. This goes over ways to use `includes` in your HTML. That way you can share one, or more, files across numerous other pages: https://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/

Comment: What kind of server is this hosted on? What type of technology is powering it (old fashioned [pure HTML, CSS, and JavaScript], ASP.NET, MVC, etc)? Are you open to using third party libraries?

Comment: It isnt hosted anywhere as of now, its just a little project I'm working on. Its currently run on pure HTML and CSS, and I know nothing of anything else you listed, nor do I know HOW to use a "third party library" though I am open to it @PerpetualJ

Comment: @justDan I'll take a look thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (Single Page Application).

> A single-page application (SPA) is a web application or web site that interacts with the user by dynamically rewriting the current page rather than loading entire new pages from a server.

Your best bet is to use a framework that provides this functionality where only part of the page (*not the whole page*) reloads when a request is being sent.

Here is a list of popular SPA frameworks:

- [EmberJS](https://emberjs.com/)
- [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/)
- [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/)

Comment: Though this isn't what the OP is asking for, it's a good alternative for smaller sites.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean for this?

JavaScript:

```
var lnk = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar a');
Array.from(lnk).forEach( a=>{
    a.removeAttribute('id');
});
document.querySelector('[href$="'+/[^/]*$/.exec(window.location.pathname)[0]+'"]').setAttribute('id','active');
```